# How to add more JSON entries into file with right format?

Tags: perl

I am trying to add via given input to JSON, but the output format is not as expected. Please suggest any changes require on this code. For testing I am passing one entry via `$data_to_json`, but I need to pass many like similar lines to JSON file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;
my $json = JSON->new;

my %data;
my $data_to_json = [ {data=>{user=>"myuser",status=>"ok"}, "host"=>"localhost","ver"=>"1.0", "remote"=> [{"host"=>"remotehost","ver"=>"1.0"}] } ];
$data{data} = $data_to_json;
my $convert = JSON->new->pretty;
print $convert->encode(\%data);
```

It returns the following output which is not expected:

```
{
   "data" : [
      {
         "ver" : "1.0",
         "data" : {
         "status" : "ok",
        "user" : "myuser"
     },
     "remote" : [
        {
           "ver" : "1.0",
           "host" : "remotehost"
        }
     ],
     "host" : "localhost"
   }
 ]
}
```

I am looking at following results format  (there are more than one record like below I need to add into JSON)

```
[
{
    "data":{
        "user": "myuser",
        "status": "ok" 
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "remote": [
        {
            "host": "remotehost",
            "ver": "1.0",
        }
     ]
  },
{
    "data":{
        "user": "myuser",
        "status": "ok" 
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "ver": "2.0",
    "remote": [
        {
            "host": "remotehost",
            "ver": "2.0",
        }
     ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer structure is not an object in JSON parlance (or a hash in Perl parlance), but an array. Use [push](http://p3rl.org/push) to add elements to an array. Also, the data can be simplified: you don't need to store the object/hash in an array, just use the object/hash directly.

```perl
my @data;
my $data_to_json = { data   => { user => 'myuser', status => 'ok' },
                     host   => 'localhost',
                     ver    => '1.0',
                     remote => [ { host => 'remotehost', ver => '1.0' } ] };
push @data, $data_to_json;
my $convert = JSON->new->pretty;
print $convert->encode(\@data);
```

Comment: In JS parlance, the outer structure *is* an object because arrays are a type of object in Javascript. In JSON parlance, the outer structure is not an object as arrays and objects are distinct data types.